# How to access a SQLite Database throughout an android applicaton?

Tags: android, sqlite

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to access a SQLite DB over multiple activities in an Android application. I tried using an application class but it will not work. Can someone please show me an example of how this would work? I basically have a tab bar setup and need to access the DB from each tab.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your DB class a singleton and you will be able to use it from all activities. Do not close the database, it will be closed automatically when the app process ends.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can get you started:

```
private MessagesDatabaseAdapter mDatabaseAdapter;
...
private void someMethod(Context context) {
mDatabaseAdapter.open();
mDatabaseAdapter.insertMessage(timestamp, number, body);
mDatabaseAdapter.close();
}
```

In your DBClass

```
            /*Inserts a message into the db */
    public void insertMessage(long timestamp, String number, String body) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TIMESTAMP, timestamp);
    initialValues.put(KEY_NUMBER, number);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
    db.insert(Constants.DATABASES_TABLE_MESSAGES, null, initialValues);
}

        /* opens the database */
public MessagesDatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

/* closes the database */
public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}
```

This [tutorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) is pretty nice, although it's not exactly what you mention you can get the fundamentals from it.

Comment: Opening and closing the database for every single operation is hardly a good idea.

Comment: This is a sample from an app that builds the table one row at a time with this single input method...I'm not working a huge db here.

Comment: It doesn't matter -- opening and closing are expensive operations, you shouldn't do them repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [Notepad Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html).

Specifically, [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) page tells you about using the DBAdapter helper class you create:

> The constructor for NotesDbAdapter takes a Context, which allows it to
>   communicate with aspects of the Android operating system. This is
>   quite common for classes that need to touch the Android system in some
>   way. The Activity class implements the Context class, so usually you
>   will just pass this from your Activity, when needing a Context.

You can instantiate and use the NotesDbAdapter from any Activity, passing in your context.